# Инспекция класса для работы с HeapAlloc

Tags: c#, .net, инспекция-кода

Нашел в спецификации C# интересный материал [A.8 Dynamic memory allocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664786(v=vs.71).aspx).

Немного переделал его для работы с x64:

```
    internal unsafe class Memory
    {
        // Heap API flags
        private const uint HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY = 0x00000008;

        // Heap API functions
        [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetProcessHeap();
        [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        private static extern int HeapSize(IntPtr hHeap, uint dwFlags, IntPtr lpMem);
        [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        private static extern IntPtr HeapAlloc(IntPtr hHeap, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwBytes);
        [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        private static extern IntPtr HeapReAlloc(IntPtr hHeap, uint dwFlags, IntPtr lpMem, UIntPtr dwBytes);
        [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        private static extern bool HeapFree(IntPtr hHeap, uint flags, IntPtr lpMem);

        // Handle for the process heap. This handle is used in all calls to the
        // HeapXXX APIs in the methods below.
        private static IntPtr ph = GetProcessHeap();

        // Private instance constructor to prevent instantiation.
        private Memory()
        {
        }

        // Allocates a memory block of the given size. The allocated memory is
        // automatically initialized to zero.
        public static void* Alloc(uint size)
        {
            void* result = HeapAlloc(ph, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, new UIntPtr(size)).ToPointer();
            if (result == null) throw new OutOfMemoryException();
            return result;
        }

        // Copies count bytes from src to dst. The source and destination
        // blocks are permitted to overlap.
        public static void Copy(void* src, void* dst, int count)
        {
            byte* ps = (byte*)src;
            byte* pd = (byte*)dst;
            if (ps > pd)
            {
                for (; count != 0; count--) *pd++ = *ps++;
            }
            else if (ps < pd)
            {
                for (ps += count, pd += count; count != 0; count--) *--pd = *--ps;
            }
        }

        // Frees a memory block.
        public static void Free(void* block)
        {
            if (!HeapFree(ph, 0, new IntPtr(block))) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        // Re-allocates a memory block. If the reallocation request is for a
        // larger size, the additional region of memory is automatically
        // initialized to zero.
        public static void* ReAlloc(void* block, uint size)
        {
            void* result = HeapReAlloc(ph, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, new IntPtr(block), new UIntPtr(size)).ToPointer();
            if (result == null) throw new OutOfMemoryException();
            return result;
        }

        // Returns the size of a memory block.
        public static int SizeOf(void* block)
        {
            int result = HeapSize(ph, 0, new IntPtr(block));
            if (result == -1) throw new InvalidOperationException();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Я тот еще нативщик, поэтому прошу опытных людей провести испекцию кода, который преимущественно будет являться заменой стандартного байтового массива (byte[]) в многопоточном приложении.

p.s. по предварительным данным HeapAlloc работает быстрее стандартной stackalloc. Правда профессиональные бенчмарки не проводил, использовал stopwatch.

Comment: Нативное выделение памяти для начала негативно влияет на сборщик мусора. Зачем вам нативная память в C#? Мне кажется, вы пытаетесь экономить на гвоздях.

Comment: @VladD, скорость выделения, скорость освобождения получаются даже быстрее чем stackalloc. Нужно это для производительности.

Comment: @VladD, можно поподробнее как именно нативное выделение влияет на коллектор?

Comment: Скорость выделения памяти в нормальных случаях ничтожно мало мала по сравнению с остальным пробегом программы. Очень не верится, что ваша программа станет быстрее, если вы обойдёте стандартные средства.

Comment: Ну, области нативной памяти становятся недоступны коллектору, и ему приходится в своих расчётах всё время эти дыры учитывать.

Comment: Расскажите лучше вашу настоящую задачу. Обыкновенное выделение памяти через `new` должно быть достаточно быстрым: это Interlocked.Increment стек-пойнтера плюс обнуление памяти. Если вы хотите и на обнулении памяти сэкономить, заведите пул кусков памяти и используйте их повторно.

Comment: @VladD, но, посудите сами, что "обойти дыру", что "втыкать" при каждом завершении метода удаляя управляемый буффер - не одно и тоже ли по перформансу?

Comment: @VladD, настоящая задача - увеличение производительности приложения. Оптимизировать стандартными средствами уже некуда (если не считать микрооптимизации, но это отдельная тема). Грубо говоря сейчас втыкает GC выделяя и удаляя много объектов Gen0. А когда GC "втыкает" - он тупо приостанавливает все потоки. Поэтому решил уйти на более низкий уровень, самостоятельно когда нужно выделять и освобождать память.

Comment: Мне не верится, что вы сможете работать с памятью скорее, чем GC, он всё-таки сложная и умная штука. Возможно, вам нужно просто уменьшить количество мелких временных объектов. Да, и может быть, какие-то из них реально являются структурами.

Comment: @VladD, по поводу пула кусков памяти - Вы имеете ввиду какой то кэширующий пул буфферов, который сохраняет в себя одинаковые данные, доступные всем потокам? Я слышал нечто подобное, но не вдавался в подробности.

Comment: Ага, именно так, пул буферов, как бы собственный аллокатор, если хотите.

Comment: раз у вас дошло до оптимизации GC, в плоть до отказа от него, то скорее всего вам нужно бороться не с GC, а с memory-трафиком, т.е. избавляться от создания временных объектов в больших количествах, а по максимуму использовать их повторно, вроде интернирования строк, и все в таком духе.

Comment: @rdorn, VladD - не всегда это возможно. Мало очень статических данных, в основном они динамически меняются. Да и не поможет это сильно, издержки на синхронизации для кэширующего пула, увеличение размера потребляемой ОЗУ (ведь пул будет активным все время работы приложения). Я попробую, но многого от этого не стоит ожидать. Буду пробовать и то и то. Так что вопрос открыт, корректный ли код в вопросе? Может что-то подправить?

Answer (score 1):

## По самой идее

> по предварительным данным HeapAlloc работает быстрее стандартной stackalloc

Это странно. Как правило, managed-память выделяется быстрее нативной, поскольку для её выделения требуется лишь сдвинуть указатель, а для выделения нативной идёт поиск достаточного свободного куска по связному списку. Со временем появляется фрагментация и искать в списке становится всё дольше. Кроме одного случая.

У тебя постоянно происходит выделение памяти на короткоживущие объекты одинакового размера. В таком случае в нативной памяти постоянно занимаются и освобождаются куски одинакового размера и они довольно быстро попадаются в списке свободных кусков.

А вот в случае managed-памяти освобождения внутри не будет, поэтому придётся постоянно выполнять дефрагментацию памяти, что занимает значительное время.

Такую проблему следует решать по-другому:

- Попробовать заменить класс на структуру, чтобы использовать память в стеке.
- Попробовать сделать переиспользуемый пулл объектов класса на достаточное количество элементов. Он уползёт куда-нибудь в долгоживущие объекты и перестанет мешаться при распределении памяти.

## По коду:

> ```
> internal unsafe class Memory
> ```

Этот класс вообще не требует unsafe-кода.

> ```
> [DllImport("Kernel32")]
> private static extern int HeapSize(IntPtr hHeap, uint dwFlags, IntPtr lpMem);
> ```

Он не `int`. Должно быть `IntPtr` с кастом в long, чтобы соблюдать битность. Но вообще он `size_t`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa366706(v=vs.85).aspx

> ```
> void* result = (...).ToPointer();
> if (result == null) throw new ...;
> return result;
> ```

```
IntPtr result = ...;
if (result == IntPtr.Zero) throw new ...;
return result;
```

> ```
> public static void Copy(void* src, void* dst, int count)
> ```

Традиционно это называется не `Copy`, а `Move`. Т. е. при копировании блоки пересекаться не должны, а при перемещении могут. И для этого уже есть готовая функция: [`RtlMoveMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt723419(v=vs.85).aspx).

> ```
> throw new OutOfMemoryException();
> throw new InvalidOperationException();
> ```

Ну хоть какое-нибудь описание в исключения?

> ```
> throw new OutOfMemoryException();
> ```

Не уверен, можно ли запросить ещё памяти, если кончился хип.
Мне почему-то кажется, что да.

Comment: Кстати, да, HeapAlloc -- это системный вызов, непонятно как он может быть быстрее нормальной аллокации на стеке. Думаю, профилирование покажет, что медленнее, причём намного.

Comment: @VladD, дефрагментация сожрёт разницу. Т. е. если ты выделил 8 байт, выделил ещё 8 managed-байт, освободил первые 8 байт и повторил это миллион раз - вероятно, тебе один и тот же кусок отдадут в unmanaged. А вот если бы они шли из той же кучи, то и managed, то там бы постоянно вертелась дефрагментация памяти, поскольку часть объектов выживает. Думаю, за счёт этого действительно может быть выигрыш, но фиксить-то надо по-другому :)

Comment: Нипанятна! Откуда возьмётся фрагментация, если stackalloc? Всё в стеке, при окончании работы функции фрейм умирает.

Comment: @VladD, ой. Я думал про managed heap. А вообще, ведь у объекта в стеке будет лишь ссылка, а сам-то объект в куче.