# Изменить размер массива динамически

Tags: c#, массивы, динамические-массивы

Например есть такой массив, как изменить его размер с 4 на другое число?

```
int[] array = new int[4];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы подходите неправильно. Если вам нужно менять размер контейнера, вы должны вместо массива использовать [`List<int>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx).

Вы не сможете изменять размер, добавляя неинициализированные элементы, но вы сможете добавить элемент в конец при помощи `Add`, в начало или середину при помощи `Insert`, или удалять по индексу при помощи `RemoveAt`.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем примере **управляемый** массив.
Напрямую - никак, только через аллокацию (выделение памяти) нового массива. Например есть метод [Array.Resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx), внутри он создает новый массив заданного размера, копирует в него содержимое старого массива и возвращает ссылку на новый массив.

---

Если очень сильно нужно изменить размер **неуправляемого** массива без аллокации нового - можно воспользоваться нативным классом (функция `HeapReAlloc`) из моего вопроса: [Инспекция класса для работы с HeapAlloc](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583249/%d0%98%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81-heapalloc)